# How to set custom icon for dll file?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, icons, embedded-resource

I have tried: `Project Properties > Application > Icon and Manifest` and browsing to my `.ico` file. The icon appears on the right of the box once its loaded but when I build my library the icon is still just the default one.

**So is it possible to embed an icon in my library and use it for the dll file itself?**

Thanks

Comment: I didn't even think Windows bothered looking in the DLL for an icon to use...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't, as windows doesn't look for icons in dlls. That's just done for exes.

Comment: Well, interesting fact: In VisualStudio, you can set a default symbol even for a library project.

Comment: It's true.  You can specify the icon for the dll right in the properties window.  But it doesn't have any effect except to increase the file size!